# MEDIA_URL path doesn't show up

Tags: django, django-settings, media-url

I have a problem with my static and media settings, so my uploaded images doesn't show up on my site page.

In my "settings.py" I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static', 'media')
)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'),
)
```

In my "models.py" I have:

```
expert_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles')
```

Some "urls.py":

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

    url(r'^experts/all/$', 'expert.views.experts', name='experts'),
    url(r'^experts/get/(?P<expert_id>\d+)/$', 'expert.views.expert', name='expert'),

)
```

And after all of that, when I go to my page, I see, that the picture have link, like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/profiles/i_vagin.jpg
```

But it must be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/profiles/i_vagin.jpg
```

So how can I fix that?

Comment: No, it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profiles/i_vagin.jpg` because your MEDIA_URL is `/media/` not `/static/media/`.

Comment: I tried to change "/media/" to "/static/media/", but still have link without "media" included... So this is not the answer.

Comment: No, which was why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media files are not, by default, served during development. To enable media file serving, you need to add the following code in your `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

*Source: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)*

**Update**

You'll also need to access images in your templates like this: `{{ expert_photo.url }}`

Comment: Yes, I read about that before create this topic and tried it again right now... No success... Still got `<img src="/static/profiles/i_vagin.jpg">` , but need  `<img src="/static/media/profiles/i_vagin.jpg">`

Comment: @s_spirit Are you accessing images in your templates like this: `{{ expert_photo.url }}`?

Comment: Of course, I'm not...:/ That was the answer. Previous developer take it through `{% static expert.expert_photo %}` and I missed this thing... All works right now, thank you.